# To close the Navigation Drawer on touch of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I am new to this Android. Here I got stuck with one problem that when I click 
on Navigation Drawer item then it give other item and then on touch of screen then Navigation Drawer get closed but back button still there.

I put **mDrawerLayout.ontouchlistener** it does work but i want that icon back on click on screen. I does not want back button

When I click on category item inside Navigation Drawer:

[image]

Then I put another adapter with different ArrayList in ExpandableListView:

[image]

But when I touch on screen then it close Navigation Drawer but back icon is still there:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set

```
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
  getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

inside your activity.

Answer (score 0):

I checked in developers.android.com. They gave one small solution. Hope this works.

```html
 private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    ...
     private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
                ) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
          return true;
        }
        // Handle your other action bar items...

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    ...
}
```